# How to sort products in Magento by new from date?

Tags: magento2, database, products, sorting, query

> I wanted to sort products by new from date , please see the query but
> it is not working perfectly

```
$collection->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft(
           ['catalog_product_entity_datetime' => 'catalog_product_entity_datetime'],
           'e.entity_id = catalog_product_entity_datetime.entity_id AND catalog_product_entity_datetime.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = "news_from_date" LIMIT 1)',
           ['value' => 'catalog_product_entity_datetime.value']
       )
        ->group('e.entity_id')
        ->order('value','asc');
```

This is giving this query but it is not working

```
    SELECT `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, IFNULL(review_summary.reviews_count, 0) AS `reviews_count`, IFNULL(review_summary.rating_summary, 0) AS `rating_summary`, `catalog_product_entity_datetime`.`value` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 AND price_index.website_id = '1'
 LEFT JOIN `review_entity_summary` AS `review_summary` ON e.entity_id = review_summary.entity_pk_value AND review_summary.store_id = 1 AND review_summary.entity_type = (SELECT `review_entity`.`entity_id` FROM `review_entity` WHERE (entity_code = 'product'))
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` ON e.entity_id = catalog_product_entity_datetime.entity_id AND catalog_product_entity_datetime.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = "news_from_date" LIMIT 1) GROUP BY `e`.`entity_id` ORDER BY `value` ASC
```

Comment: Could you kindly provide the complete collection code? I'm uncertain about which collection you were utilizing in this context. Additionally, it would be beneficial if you could specify the version of Magento 2 that you were using. This information will aid in providing accurate assistance.